# Best algorithm to sort the given values

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

Suppose I have the following values:-

```
xyz12@abc
xyz1@abc
xyz15@abc
xyz2@abc
xyz22@abc
```

I want the sorted output to be in form:-

```
xyz1@abc
xyz2@abc
xyz12@abc
xyz15@abc
xyz22@abc
```

If I use strcmp, then it will compare by each character and will give xyz1@ > xyz12 as @ > 2 which I don't want. What different algorithms can I use to sort this in the required format??

Comment: The Google keyword you're looking for is "natural sort".

Comment: You are confusing `sorting algorithm` and `comparation criterium`

Comment: Presumably, given extra rows `pqr190@example.com` and `pqr91@example.com`, the results should list both those before the `xyz*` names, but `pqr91@example.com` should be listed before `pqr190@example.com` because 91 comes before 190 numerically.  It is as yet undefined whether `XYZ7@ABC` should come before, after or in the midst of the original entries.

Comment: Treat each character as indicie in a base256 number system and using each characters ascii value apply your favorite sorting algorithm.

Comment: You can use any sort, just write your own compare function, that compares characters only up to @.

Comment: @oli: post your comment as an answer man. Awesome stuff.

Comment: @rahul: absolutely fantastic question. I wanted to give you +5 but thats not possible. The natural sort is something new to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google keyword you're looking for is "natural sort".

Comment: Absolutely fantastic, specially the codinghorror article I read about natural sort. Three cheers Oli.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how the sort utility is implemented:

```
$ cat test.txt | sort
xyz12@abc
xyz15@abc
xyz1@abc
xyz22@abc
xyz2@abc
```

Now with -V switch...

```
$ cat test.txt | sort -V
xyz1@abc
xyz2@abc
xyz12@abc
xyz15@abc
xyz22@abc
```

http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/sort.c

Answer (score 0):

if XYZ is alway the same, than use [Counting sort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/40549/Counting-sort) on the integer value. Otherwise it is probably the easiest way to use some generic comparison based sort with custom comparator (i.e. [Merge sort](http://en.algoritmy.net/article/39650/Merge-sort)).

By generic I mean to use some preprogrammed sorting algorithm, which is prepared to accept some comparator function (returns typically 1 if A > B, -1 if A < B, 0 otherwise)

Answer (score -1):

I strongly suggest you to take a look at this website:

http://www.c.happycodings.com/Sorting_Searching/index.html

There you have a branch of sorting algorithms in C. Obviously take those whose performance is better (nlogn).